# JavaScript and CSS hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

When changing a color of a paragraph element, CSS hover stops working.

I made a demo to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/woan6b64/

After I change `<p>'s` color, the hover selector stops working.

My question is:

- How can I change the hover effect with JavaScript?
- How can I get hovering to work after a color change?

JSFiddle code:

```js
var shift = 0;

function change() {
  if (shift === 0) {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'Good! Now click the box again.';
    shift = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'Hover effect is now broken :(';
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

p:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='box' onclick='change()'>
  <p id='text'>
    Click me for this box to change color. (Notice how I turn green when hovered)
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it is an option @Syden

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After setting the color, the hover is overridden. Use !important to force it:

```
p:hover{
  color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: This ain't right! Don't use important if not strictly necessary this is bad practice...

Comment: While this is the solution, [!important should be used as a last resort](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/500x/76500203/important-does-not-fix-your-bad-css.jpg). You should make use of [**higher specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) instead :)

Answer (score 4):

Stop it! Don't use `!important` if not necessary... your problem is that you set the color to black.

```
document.getElementById("text").style.color = "";
```

This will make the color inherit the right style.

How ever, this ain't the right solution either. You should add class to the box and then do:

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

p:hover {
  color: green;
}

#box.altered {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.altered p:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="this.classList.toggle('altered')">
  <p id='text'>
    Click me for this box to change color. (Notice how I turn green when hovered)
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but it also depends whether they want green on hover after being clicked the first time. That wasn't specified in the original question.

Comment: True, still adding class is much better option, and adding important to the green will make it work only with green... so

Comment: Yeah, a class is definitely the best option! All depends on the original goal, really.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class

```
// document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "black";
// document.getElementById("text").style.color = "white";
document.getElementById("text").classList.add("purple");

.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

Comment: The way you did it would've worked, but this way is much cleaner and prevents adding it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with specificity, so you'll need to use `!important` on the color property to force it.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woan6b64/1/)

NB: This isn't best practice. Depending on your intent, adding a class or simply unsetting the color may be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with pure JS you need to listen for `onmouseover` event and `onmouseout` event, check the code that I made

```js
var textElement = document.getElementById("text");
var defaultColor = textElement.style.color;

textElement.onmouseover = function(event) {
var currentElement = event.target;
currentElement.style.color = "red";
}

textElement.onmouseout = function(event) {
var currentElement = event.target;
currentElement.style.color = defaultColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<p id="text">
I am a text that change its text color :D
</p>
</div>
```